# Cascades of delegates and hijacking delegate callbacks in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, delegation

Say I write a UITextField subclass and want to have control over the text written into it by the user. I would set the input field's delegate to be myself and implement `-textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`.

However, I would still want to allow whatever part of code uses me as a text field to implement the usual delegate methods. An approach for that would be to store a second delegate reference and map them like so:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    super.delegate = self;
    return self;
}

- (void)setDelegate:(id)delegate {
    self.nextDelegate = delegate;
}

- (id)delegate {
    return self.nextDelegate;
}
```

I would then proceed to implement *all* UITextFieldDelegate methods and forward them to the next delegate as I wish. Obviously, I may want to modify some parameters before passing them on to the next delegate, like in `-textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`.
Another problem I'm thinking of is when the user's sets `nextDelegate` to the text field itself (for whatever reason), resulting in an infinite loop.

Is there a more elegant way to hijack delegate callbacks like in the example code I posted?

Comment: What you're describing is basically sound.  There may be other ways to finesse a given problem, but your cascaded delegate is a general approach that should work.  The devil is in the details of course -- more than a couple of ways to foul it up.

Comment: @HotLicks Actually, it's not sound at all, in fact it won't work.  The code from UITextField will use `self.delegate` to send messages to the delegate, not `super.delegate`  which means that the delegate methods will actually go to `self.nextDelegate`

Comment: @JeremyP It is working though. Would you mind elaborating on your theory why it should not work?

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr the only way it could be working is if, internally, the UITextField object is using the instance variable to send messages to the delegate.  If it were to use the property (as it should really), it would invoke *your* delegate method, to get the delegate, not the super delegate method.

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr Nikolai's answer explains the issue in more detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach is the overridden `delegate` accessor: There's no guarantee that Apple's code always uses the `delegate` ivar directly and **does not** use the getter to access the delegate. In that case it would just call through to the `nextDelegate`, bypassing your sneaked in `self` delegate.

You might have checked that your approach works in the current implementation but this could also change in future UIKit versions.

> Is there a more elegant way to hijack delegate callbacks like in the example code I posted?

No, I'm not aware of any elegant solutions. You could not override the delegate accessor and instead set up secondary delegate (to which you have to manually pass all delegate messages).

To solve the actual problem of filtering text input it might be worthwhile looking into

```
- (void)replaceRange:(UITextRange *)range withText:(NSString *)text;
```

This method is implemented by `UITextField` (as it adopts `UITextInput`) and could be overridden to filter the `text` argument.

Comment: That sounds like a really interesting approach. However, overriding doesn't seem to help. The user input is preserved even if I do not call super or call super with modified text. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @ChristianSchnorr I'm not sure if the suggested override can do what you need. Maybe you find some other helpful method to override in `UITextInput`. On the other hand I'd like to propose another approach which avoids subclassing. I'm adding a new answer for that.

Comment: I had a look at UITextInput but the method you suggested is the only one that seemed remotely helpful to me, but it apparently not called. As for subclassing in this context, I really do think that it is the best approach because I want the text field itself to know what text it is allowed to accept and a potential delegate should not need to worry about that. Looking forward to your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're thinking about this correctly, and the approach you outlined will work fine (I've done it).

There's no circularity issue because you shouldn't expose nextDelegate in the subclass's public interface, so no caller will have the chance to setup a cycle.  (You could also test in the setter that `delegate != self`.

It would be better, though, if you could avoid this altogether.  For example, if you just want to tweak the text field text as it changes, you can get the control event:

```
[self addTarget:self action:@selector(didChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Then,

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(id)sender {
    self.text = [self alteredText];  
}

- (NSString *)alteredText {
    // do whatever transform to user input you wish, like change user input 'a' to 'x'
    return [self.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"a" withString:@"x"];
}
```

This will work as well, but with the odd side effect that the delegate won't see the alteredText in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:`.  That's fixable by making `alteredText` public and having the class customers call it instead of the standard getter.

Comment: Your approach also resets the caret to full opacity every time the text 'maybe' changes. This would be the case if I remove whitespace, and the user tries to add whitespace to the end of the string. Even though the text does not actually change, the carte does not blink.

Comment: Also what I meant by cascading delegates were not circularity issues, but rather the following hierarchy: CreditCardField < NumericInputField < UITextField. Basically both my custom classes would have the 'next delegate' thing which could a) cause trouble with instance variable naming (can I really avoid this if someone else decides to subclass one of these and chooses the same name for a property?) and b) adds a lot of code because I have to implement all the delegate methods. I was initally thinking of another class which acts as a cascade and passes the callbacks along a list of delegates.

Comment: The other thing to think about is UI style.  One could argue that its wrong for the text to not reflect the user input (it could seem broken).  A gentler approach might be to allow unconstrained input, then change when you get didEndEditing.

Comment: Obviously it could seem broken if the user does not know what is going on, but he would wonder just as much why half of his input disappeared once he finished editing, wouldn't he? Also, in most cases where I'd use this, the user would be aware of him only being allowed to enter a set of characters, like for credit card information.

Comment: Up to you of course.  Anyway, as I say, the approach you outlined works just fine. Adding an NSSet of delegate part of the public interface would work too (though that approach I've never tried).

Answer (score 0):

All of the problems with subclassing can be avoided by using a different approach of intercepting delegate messages: A "delegate proxy".

The idea is to use an intermediate object (derived from `NSProxy`) that either responds to a delegate message or passes it along to the next delegate. It's basically what you did by subclassing the UITextField but instead of using the text field object we'll use a custom object that handles only the interception of some delegate messages.

These customized delegate proxys form a set of reusable building blocks which are simply plugged into each other to customize the behavior of any object that uses delegation.

Here's an example ([code on github](https://gist.github.com/NikolaiRuhe/bacd3f57ebb7b2c4f22b)) of a chain of delegates:

```
UITextField -> TextFilterDelegate -> SomeViewController
```

The `UITextField` passes delegate messages to `TextFilterDelegate` which responds to `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` and passes other delegate messages on to its own delegate (the view controller).